# Check Widget is Placed on Android Screen

Tags: android, widget, homescreen

Can someone tell me how to check that my widget have been placed on the homescreen?

I have some code in my app that should run only if the widget is placed on the homescreen.

Comment: Hello, did you had a look at my answer? I think it might help.. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to store that information yourself.  I usually use the application preferences, but you could use anything.  Generally widgets use services to communicate, so your code that does stuff is likely in a service, but using the preference allows any portion of your app to access this.

In your widget class that extends AppWidgetProvider the onEnabled is called when the widget is put on a homescreen and the onDeleted is (usually) called when it's removed.  onDisabled is called when all copies are removed.

So in the code of your widget provider:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    setWidgetActive(true);
    context.startService(new Intent(appContext, WidgetUpdateService.class));
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    setWidgetActive(false);
    context.stopService(new Intent(appContext, WidgetUpdateService.class));
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

private void setWidgetActive(boolean active){
    Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(Constants.WIDGET_ACTIVE, active);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Elsewhere in code, you would check to see if the widget is active by:

```
public boolean isWidgetActive(Context context){
    Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return prefs.getBoolean(Constants.WIDGET_ACTIVE, false);
}
```

Comment: Aargh nice! Thanks, had not thought of onDisabled(), 
It will only be run when you have removed all widget from the homescreen of your app exactly what i need. I was using: onDeleted(), witch gets run every time you delete a widget.

Comment: There are some cases the above don't cover, and I'm looking for solutions: (1) user cleared shared preferences - there's widget, but you don't know about it (2) user regret between "add widget" and pressing "ok" - but enable was called, no widget

Comment: Please have a look at answer below ;-)

Comment: Storing this flag in database or SharedPreferences is good in some scenarios, when you want to know whether the user ever used or activated (not currently) widget feature of the app. (I know this is not the direct answer to the SO question)

Answer (score 56):

Just saying, but...

```
    int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this,MyAppWidgetProvider.class));

    Toast.makeText(this, "Number of widgets: "+ids.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer: querying the AppWidgetManager and gettings the ids is the correct way checking if and how many widgets are placed in the homescreen.

Comment: I can also confirm that this is the correct answer. Don't waste time following larsona1's answer and ending up with fragile code to maintain.

Comment: only problem is that sometimes it returns a number of ids even if no widgets are displayed

Comment: voted up but... if you remove widget from screen `getAppWidgetIds()` still returning values

Comment: You can reproduce my case if using widget config Activity and if you finish it without to create the widget, it calls `onUpdate` in `AppWidgetProvider` anyway.

Comment: Any fix for these issues @Choletski? I'm having the same issue where there are no widgets, but I'm still getting values back.

Comment: The only instance that I've seen this return the incorrect number of ids is when I've just removed the widget and ran the code while the undo snackbar was still available (Pixel Device using Pixel Launcher), which leads me to believe that the situation I was seeing was simply caused by the system still maintaining the binding after the widget was removed for the duration of the undo snackbar to avoid redoing work if the user decided to undo the action.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old question, but looking at this today I saw that there are a couple of problems with the accepted answer from @larsona1:

1. if the user cleared the shared preferences - there's still widget, but the app won't know about it.
2. if the user regret between "add widget" and before pressing "ok" - onEnabled will be called anyway, and a widget will be registered in the home screen even though there is no widget, and no way to remove it later. (it may be a bug in ADT home launcher).

I found a solution to the first problem.
No shared preferences are needed at all, since it's unreliable anyway. It has to be checked in runtime.

```
// in some class you define a static variable, say in S.java
static boolean sWidgetMayExist = true;
```

In your widget provider:

```
// MyAppWidgetProvider.java
// to respond to runtime changes, when widgets are added and removed
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    S.sWidgetMayExist = true;
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
    S.sWidgetMayExist = true;
}
```

And, in your service code add this:

```
AppWidgetManager manager = null;
RemoteViews views = null;
ComponentName widgetComponent = null;

    // ..and in your update thread

    if (!S.sWidgetMayExist) { return; }

if (manager == null || widgetComponent == null) {
    widgetComponent = new ComponentName(c,
            MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
    manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
}

if (manager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetComponent) == null) {
    S.sWidgetMayExist = false;
}
```

Comment: According to this page [1] problem 2 seems to be a bug that was fixed with Android 2.1 and later. I tested it with Android 4.1.2 and the onDelete and onDisabled methods were called correctly. 

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/4agiDfaGvDw

Comment: See Waza_Be's answer, seems to work and requires much less code.

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard My answer is 6 months older than Waza's. So I didn't inspect it when answering. But reviewing it now, I'm not sure it covers the edge cases I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

@Waza_Be is right as looking at the "AppWidgetIds" list to know the number of active widgets (those installed on your homescreen) is the correct way to know this information.

However, keep in mind that you SHOULD don't have to look at this by yourself.

Check the official Android documentation for best practice about widgets :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider

The right approach is to override only the onUpdate() method and iterate through the list of "active" widgets :

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

And as your own widget provider overrides AppWidgetProvider, you will NOT go into the onUpdate() method if you have no widgets active on the home screen!

See the onReceive() code of Android AppWidgetProvider that checks already for you that "appWidgetIds.length > 0":

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Protect against rogue update broadcasts (not really a security issue,
    // just filter bad broacasts out so subclasses are less likely to crash).
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int[] appWidgetIds = extras.getIntArray(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
            if (appWidgetIds != null && appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
                this.onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), appWidgetIds);
            }
        }
    }

(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
boolean widgetExists(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo info = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
    return (info != null);
}
```

From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#getAppWidgetInfo(int)) for `appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo()`:

> If the appWidgetId has not been bound to a provider yet, or you don't have access to that appWidgetId, null is returned.