# Android How to detect if a widget is enabled programmatically?

Tags: android, widget, detect, launcher

I'm working on a widget app, but I don't know how to check, from code, if a widget is enabled (placed on HomeScreen) programmatically.

Please help me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AppWidgetProvider` has a method `onEnabled` where you can set a boolean variable. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11815421/661079