# Get the currently active widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I have got all the widget app list.My problem is that I am not able to know that which widget is currently active in the phone.
I am getting the list of widget apps by this code,

```
AppWidgetManager manager1=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctx);
        List<AppWidgetProviderInfo>infoList=manager1.getInstalledProviders();
        for(AppWidgetProviderInfo info:infoList)
        {
           String component = ""+info.provider;
           Log.i("Widget", ""+component);

        }
```

ctx is the object of Context.

I am able to get the name of currently active package name of Applications but in case of Widgets, I am not.

Comment: Here is the solution for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836724/check-widget-is-placed-on-android-screen/8837570#8837570

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get the package name of widget(another application) from my own application.@Sridhar You are giving me the solution to do activeCheck in my application only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this but u may Try using getRunningServices
As These widgets communicates with their apps with internal broadcast receivers so u can not intercept that

Answer (score 2):

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Example Here : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/138412-android-20-list-of-running-applications/